# ASP.NET Core w/ Tools for Docker EnvironmentName for Stage

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, docker

I created the configuration `Staging` for my ASP.NET Core using **Docker Desktop for Windows** and **VS Tools for Docker**. When I run the configuration `Staging` the `env.EnvironmentName` keeps coming up as `Production` rather than `Staging`.

In the file `docker-compose.dev.staging.yml` I set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Staging` also. But that doesn't help either. Granted, I need to put it somewhere else also since when I publish I want `Staging` to get the `Staging` `EnvironmentName`.

```
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

So, it looks like there is a bug in the `Visual Studio Tools for Docker`. It doesn't respect the configuration setting and grabs the file `docker-compose.dev.release.yml` rather than `docker-compose.dev.staging.yml`. So, you need to change that actual file if you want to change the environment to `staging`. So, when debugging in `staging` added the following to your `release` file:

```
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
```

And all will be well with the world. You will need to do that when deploying also, to the main `docker-compose` file. Annoying, but what else are you going to do?

Also, add the image name like:

```
image: docker.appcatalyst.com:5000/symptom_checker_pam_cms:staging
```

Then you will get the `staging` tag for deployment to staging. Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon.

**Update 2**

Now, that I understand how Docker works. Basically you need to pass the environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file. So, on the server that is running your `staging` environment you would add what I put above and then `docker up` with that yaml file. As for on your own machine, if you want to work with your `stage` setting you would need to just add/remove (or comment out) the environment settings. Kind of a pain. Hopefully `VS Tools for Docker` fixes this behavior for debugging purposes. It would make programming slightly easier.

Answer (score 2):

When VS runs docker-compose commands, it looks for the following yaml files in order:

1. docker-compose.yml
2. docker-compose.override.yml
3. docker-compose.vs.debug.yml|docker-compose.vs.release.yml (for Debug|Release respectively)

We don't support user-defined yaml files like docker-compose.dev.staging.yml yet.

The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT has been set in docker-compose.override.yml, where is the place for defining the settings to run the app on local machine.

```
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

You can change Development to Staging in that file.

Comment: How do you add the other files, if I choose 'Add' the list is empty.  It appears to be locked down!  I have a `docker-compost.override.yml` file, but I want to add one for `release`...?